# Why doesn't my argument pass to CMD in Windows Forms app?

Tags: c#, cmd

This is my first Windows forms app.
I'm trying to pick a folder and list all files in that folder to a txt file.

This just instantly close the console window without passing the arguments.
If I put it in a bat file it works like it should.
Any ideas?

```
myPath = fbd.SelectedPath;

Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
psi.Arguments = "/K for /r " + myPath + " %%g in (*) do echo %%~ng >> " + myPath + "test.txt";
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Can you show the whole code around this line? And the exact value for _myPath_?

Comment: @Steve - Edited my question code, I get the path from FolderBrowserDialog, but the path on my computer is D:/Test/

Comment: I can see two problems: _myPath_ doesn't contains the final backslash and the _g_ I don't know what is meant for. The command shell gives error with that letter

Comment: @Steve - Sorted the final backslash now, thanks! But I'm not sure why the letter g don't work. My working bat file looks like this, for /r D:/Test/ %%g in (*) do echo %%~ng >> D:/Test/test.txt

Comment: Visual studio adds spaces on its own... shouldn't be one btw %% and the letter

Comment: @Steve - How did you manage to get the command shell error?

Comment: Put the whole command in quotes, the file paths in quotes, and don't double the percent in `%g`; that's only required in batch files. For example: `"/k \"for /r \"" + myPath + "\" %g in (*) do echo %~ng >> \"" + myPath + "\\test.txt\"\""`. Using `/K` instead of `/c` causes cmd to stay open after the command runs; is that intentional? Also you can put an `@` in front of `echo` to prevent echoing the command to the console.

Comment: @eryksun - This is working! Thanks! You should add this as an answer so I can accept it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole /k or /c command in quotes [*]. Use quotes around the file paths in case they contain spaces. And don't double the percent in the `%g` loop variable. That's only required in batch files. For example:

```
"/k \"for /r \"" + myPath + "\" %g in (*) do echo %~ng >> \"" + myPath + "\\test.txt\"\""
```

---

[*] Quoting the entire command isn't necessary in this case because the first character of the command isn't a quote. However, it's a good practice in general since cmd strips off the first and last quote if a command starts with a quote. This breaks a command such as `"C:\\some path\\command.exe" "C:\\another path\\file.ext"`, which cmd would execute as `C:\some path\command.exe" "C:\another path\file.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

why you are not directly running your .bat file ?
save whatever you want your application to do on a .bat file place it in the "bin" folder of your application, then add a namespace `using system.diagonostics ;` and generate and event like form load or button click and then write the following code `process.start("name of your .bat file")`

Comment: missed a semicolon in the second line of code- my bad

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like this, but I would have to create the bat file from the C# app since there will be different options to pick from in the end. Can't belive it's so complicated to get this done without a bat file :(